# c++ u8 literal char override

Tags: c++, c++11, utf-8, char

I tried to override character literals in order to make them **char16_t**, **wchar_t**, **char32_t**, and **char** by using *u*, *U*, *L*, and *u8* prefixes.It worked for all except *u8*. See below:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;
int main(){
cout<<"\'a\'----"<<'a'<<endl;
cout<<"L \'a\'----"<<L'a'<<endl;
cout<<"u \'a\'----"<<u'a'<<endl;
cout<<"U \'a\'----"<<U'a'<<endl;
//cout<<"u8 \'a\'----"<<u8'a'<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Consolse output:

```
'a'----a
L 'a'----97
u 'a'----97
U 'a'----97
```

When I uncomment the u8 line, I get following error:

```
'u8' was not declared in this scope prog.cpp
```

Do you know why doesn't it work?

Comment: Don't post images of text, especially not links to images (links can go stale). Copy-paste the actual text into the body of the question instead. And if you are asking about build errors, then please include the build errors too (as text, in full, complete and without editing).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/

u8 is intended for string literals while u, U, and L are intended for character literals.

In the following line you are adding the u8 prefix to a character literal.
cout<<"u8 \'a\'----"<

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was for chars.

Answer (score 1):

`u8` chars are [C++17 feature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal). Make sure your compiler supports it and you have enabled it.